# mikro-orm Cascade.REMOVE, is it only for RDBMS?

Tags: mikro-orm

I am using mikro-orm with MongoDB and trying to do a Cascade.REMOVE but i can not get it work.

Business entity:

```
@Entity({ collection: "business" })
export class BusinessModel implements BusinessEntity {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public _id!: ObjectId;

    @Property()
    public name!: string;

    @Property()
    public description!: string;

    @OneToMany({ entity: () => LocationModel, fk: "business", cascade: [Cascade.ALL] })
    public locations: Collection<LocationModel> = new Collection(this);
}

export interface BusinessModel extends IEntity<string> { }
```

Location entity:

```
@Entity({ collection: "location" })
export class LocationModel implements LocationEntity {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public _id!: ObjectId;

    @Property()
    public geometry!: GeometryEmbedded;

    @ManyToOne({ entity: () => BusinessModel})
    public business!: BusinessModel;

    public distance?: number;
}

export interface LocationModel extends IEntity<string> { }
```

Business Data:

```
_id: 5cac818273243d1439866227
name: "Prueba"
description: "Prueba eliminacion"
```

Location Data:

```
_id: 5cac9807179e380df8e43b6c
geometry: Object
business: 5cac818273243d1439866227

_id: 5cacc941c55fbb0854f86939
geometry: Object
business: 5cac818273243d1439866227
```

And the code:

```
export default class BusinessData {
    private businessRepository: EntityRepository<BusinessModel>;

    public constructor(@inject(OrmClient) ormClient: OrmClient) {
        this.businessRepository = ormClient.em.getRepository(BusinessModel);
    }

    public async delete(id: string): Promise<number> {
        return await this.businessRepository.remove(id);
    }
}
```

The "business" is correctly removed but all related "locations" continue there.

The log only show:

> [query-logger] db.getCollection("business").deleteMany() [took 0 ms]

Comment: Just curious - did you really got this from the query logger, or did you remove the where part? If so, are you sure you are providing value for the `id` parameter?

Comment: No, I didn't remove the where part and I provided value for the id parameter.
Changing the code to:
`public async delete(id: string): Promise<number> {
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
    console.log(id);
    return await this.businessRepository.remove(id);
}`
Here is the output after the entity discovery, without removing anything:
`5cac818273243d1439866227
[query-logger] db.getCollection("business").deleteMany() [took 0 ms]`

Comment: Just checked the code, its missing only in the query logger, the condition is not omitted when querying the database. Will fix that asap, it looks pretty scary :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cascades work on application level, so for all drivers, including mongo.

The problem here is that you are removing the `Business` entity by id. You need to remove it by reference - provide the entity and be sure you have the collection populated, otherwise ORM does not know what entities to cascade remove.

Try it like this:

```
export default class BusinessData {
  public async delete(id: string): Promise<number> {
    const business = await this.businessRepository.findOne(id, ['locations'])
    return await this.businessRepository.remove(business);
  }
}
```

Your approach with removing by id would work only if the entity was already loaded in identity map (aka managed by EM), including the `locations` collection.

Comment: Yeah, it's working. Thank you (I hope I'm not being too nuisance)

Comment: Absolutely not! Thanks for good questions! I will make a FAQ page based on those in the near future.